# How to play the attached bar (same note on both hands)

Tags: piano

It may be a simple question but I am not sure how to play the attached measures.

The left hand plays C for 4 beats, the right hand after 2 beats should also play the same C note, but the left hand is still pressing the C.
Something similar occurs in the third measure. I highlighted the problem notes here: [image].

Any explanation will be helpful.
Please keep in mind that I am beginner

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bar 3: The left hand plays the chord, with your left thumb playing the B.

Just before the second beat of the bar, you lift your left thumb, and play the same B with your right hand on beat 2, 3, and 4.

Similar thing in bar 1: When it's time to play the C with the right hand, lift the left hand finger from the same C note.

To do this with pedals, you'd need a piano with 3 pedals, while the simple nature of this tune suggests (imho) that the simple approach I suggested above is implied.

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonable that you can't hold a note *and* play it again, so you hold as long as you can, then play it again. But, since it's feasible to pedal each bar, as a particular chord lasts a whole bar, using pedal, it can all work.